# Laravel 4 - Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in \bootstrap\compiled.php

Tags: installation, xampp, laravel, composer-php

I'm having a hard time installing Laravel 4 on Windows 8 + Xampp.

Here's the setup:
- Xampp 1.8.1
- Composer is installed globally

I install Laravel with the usual "composer create-project laravel/laravel projectname". It installs fine.

But when I navigate to the public folder of the framework, I get dozens of Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in \bootstrap\compiled.php errors.
On lines : 439, 221, 137, 154. The 4 errors are repeated indefinitely until the request times out.

Troubleshooting done so far:
- Tried on 2 seperate machines with the same setup.
- Re-ran Composer update.
- Instead of using create-project, I downloaded the framework and ran Composer install.
- Tried to setup up virtual hosts instead of accessing localhost/projectname/public.
- Searched online for 2 hours. Read every Laravel 4 install tutorial.

Any clues on what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks

-- EDIT --
Here are the lines causing the problem inside of compiled.php

Line 137 section :

```
    $abstract = $this->getAlias($abstract);
    if (isset($this->instances[$abstract])) {
        return $this->instances[$abstract];
    }
```

Line 154 section :

```
protected function getConcrete($abstract)
{
    if (!isset($this->bindings[$abstract])) {
        return $abstract;
    } else {
        return $this->bindings[$abstract]['concrete'];
    }
}
```

Line 221 section :

```
protected function getAlias($abstract)
{
    return isset($this->aliases[$abstract]) ? $this->aliases[$abstract] : $abstract;
}
```

Line 439 section :

```
public function make($abstract, $parameters = array())
{
    if (isset($this->deferredServices[$abstract])) {
        $this->loadDeferredProvider($abstract);
    }
    return parent::make($abstract, $parameters);
}
```

-- NEW FIND --
Using Wampserver works, instead of using Xampp.

Comment: "Any clues on what I might be doing wrong?" Not posting the lines of code that are causing the error?

Comment: I've edited the question with the culprit code.  Note that I've tried with Wampserver instead of Xampp, and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encountered the same error when using Xampp. I fixed it by disabling the eAccelerator extension in php.ini. Try commenting out the following line: `zend_extension = "path\to\xampp\php\ext\php_eaccelerator_ts.dll"` in your php.ini file.